# Twitter API get tweets based on the user's email

Tags: twitter

I was wondering.

I want to access the tweets by using email address of the people, I already have the email addresses and then I want to search via API some statistics about the people's tweets.

Is this possible?

Any help or workaround will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The email addresses of Twitter users are not accessible through the API.  This is a deliberate design decision by the Twitter development team for security and privacy.

The users in question would need to provide you with their email address and Twitter username.  this would let you perform the sort of search you are describing.